# NSString to NSUUID convert

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

how to convert from NSString to NSUUID ? i got the answer for conversion of, NSUUID to NSString but vice versa could not found.like this is my string @"12033030303" alloc NSUUID using this string  any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`@"12033030303"` is not possible to convert to NSUUID, as Universally Unique Identifier has specification (for example look at [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier)), this means any random string can't be converted to NSUUID.

`initWithUUIDString` should be the method you're looking for, but it works only if UUID is valid.

```
NSUUID *uuid = [[NSUUID alloc] initWithUUIDString:@"A5D59C2F-FE68-4BE7-B318-95029619C759"];
```